# How to test privileged packaged apps on Firefox for Desktop?

Tags: firefox, firefox-os, marketplace

It is possible to distribute a [packaged app](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Marketplace/Options/Packaged_apps) via Firefox Marketplace for installation on *Firefox for Desktop*. Apps for Firefox OS devices I can test comfortably via *about:app-manager* either on a USB connected device, or with the simulator.

*How can I test a packaged app on Firefox for Desktop?*

[image: Annotated screenshot showing distribution options]

## Update

I found that I can debug an app that I have installed from Marketplace by starting it with the `-debug` option and an optional port number:

```
 C:\Users\Felix\AppData\Roaming\thetacontrol-56cab87ea3eecf190668cfb505f92c56>"Theta Control.exe" -debug 6000
```

The next step is to connect to the port from Firefox developer tools:

[image: Annotated screenshot showing connection via menu]

Still I don't know how to debug an app that is not (yet) on Marketplace.

Answer (score 3):

Didn't found the way to debug privileged app either, so I've created bug on bugzilla, vote, please to solve this issue faster: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1038533

Answer (score -1):

You can refer to [debugging guideline](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Marketplace/Options/Open_web_apps_for_desktop#Can_I_debug_my_apps_when_they_are_running_on_a_desktop.3F) of web apps for Friefox desktop.

> To access the console (and other remote developer tools), start the
>   app from a command line with the -debug flag  and optionally
>   specifying a port (default: 6000). For example, on a Mac the Mykzilla
>   test app is started with:
>
> > `/Applications/Mykzilla.app/Contents/MacOS/webapprt -debug 6000`
>
> Then, in Firefox, on the Developer Tools menu click Connect… and
>   connect to the “localhost” host at the port you specified. After
>   clicking Connect in Firefox, go back to your app and confirm the
>   connection. Then return to Firefox and select a “tab” (i.e. an open
>   window in your app) or “Main Process” to debug the Web Runtime’s
>   chrome code.
>
> Then a copy of Firefox’s Remote Developer Tools should open in a new
>   window, and it should be connected to the “tab” you selected.

Comment: Thanks @Channy. I already mentioned in my question that I found how to debug an app installed from Firefox Marketplace. For testing, however, I also need to know: *How do I create the desktop app (`.exe` on Windows) without first uploading it to Marketplace?*